# Remove element from array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am working on nodejs/express

I want to delete element in array in mongoose

i have document in this format

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e19223e50551504b316c0"), 
    "username" : "nikhil", 
    "email" : "nikhil@itradicals.com", 
    "password" : "$2a$10$f3NvrTywIezlzKcZLWSU0O98gn6Mc.Q8B0ZNEDG2F66f4rwyo65Yu", 
    "companyname" : "itr", 
    "role" : "vendor", 
    "verify" : "true", 
    "createddate" : ISODate("2017-12-10T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "account" : [
        {
            "Region" : [
                "North America", 
                "Africa", 
                "Asia"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Category" : [
                "Group 1", 
                "Group 2", 
                "Group 3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> i want to remove only Region field using mongoose query i m getting
>   data dyanamically so user can delete any array either it is Region or
>   Category. i m getting array name which i want to delete in parameter
>   "field".

```
module.exports.setupAccount = function(id,field,callback){
        var query = { _id: id};
        User.findOneAndUpdate(query,{ $set: { account.Region:[] }}, callback);
}
```

i am new to nodejs and mongoose
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to keep the empty document after removing the field you can simply [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) the entire element from the array:

```
module.exports.setupAccount = function(id,field,callback){
    var query = { _id: id };
    User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $pull: { "account": { field: { $exists: true } } } }, callback);
}
```

Comment: i used this and that help me to solve my problem  field is dynamic so i need to use it in bracket.

Comment: use  [field]  do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function.

Use computed property names to dynamically pass the field to unset and query expression.

Query to verify for array existence followed by `$unset` to remove array.

$ positional operator to dynamically locate array based on query criteria. You can hardcode the array index if you know the array position.

```
module.exports.setupAccount = function(id, field, callback){
   var query = { "_id": id, ['account.' + field]:{"$exists":true}};
   var unset = {"$unset":{['account.$.' + field]:""}};
   User.findOneAndUpdate(query, unset, callback);
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but it left empty documnet .i don't need empty document